# Connection between Users and People in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph API I'm fetching a list of users using the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

After that, I want to check if a user is an actual person. For that, I'm planning to use People endpoint.

However, I can't find a method that will return all people in the organization. Users can also represent a room or a group and I want to be able to differentiate them. The only options that I could see are:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/people
```

But they only return people that are related to a user with the provided id.

Is there a solution for getting a corresponding Person object for every User in the organization?

Answer (score 2):

The `/people` endpoint can only return a person object if there is a connection between the `person` and the `user`.

Consider what a [`person`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/person) represents:

> An aggregation of information about a person from across mail, contacts, and social networks. People can be local contacts, contacts from social networking or your organization's directory, and people from recent communications (such as email and Skype).

If the `user` and the `person` are not connected in some way, there aren't enough sources to aggregate for a response. More importantly, the sources for `someone@someplace.com` will be different between two `user` records (i.e. I'm connected with them on Skype and LinkedIn, you've only emailed them once a while back).

Also note that to pull a *single* person, you need to provide that person's id:

```
`/me/people/{id}`
```

Comment: If i want to fetch the single person using
    "/me/people/{id}"
and that person is not connected to "me", wouldn't I just get an empty response or an error?

Comment: Also, would a "people response" for a user contain a Person object for that user?

Comment: A `person` is an aggregated object. So it consists of the `user`, any `contact` records in your mailbox, emails, Skype conversations, etc. Long-term I would expect to see it also incorporate LinkedIn and other social network data (assuming you've connected them to your user). As for why it gives an empty `200`, it likely should return an error that it couldn't find that `person` but at the moment it just returns no content whatsoever.